# How to get the Swing MetaWidget to adjust its size dynamically

Tags: java, swing, metawidget

I am using SwingMetaWidget. In my code I have a Dialog to which I pass a domain object dynamically and that will lead to different number of components based on the domain object. I would like the metawidget to return its preferredSize based on the inspection results. How can I achieve this. 
To illustrate my point, let us look at the Tutorial example.

**Main Code:**

```
package com.myapp;

import javax.swing.*;
import org.metawidget.swing.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Person person = new Person();

        SwingMetawidget metawidget = new SwingMetawidget();
        metawidget.setToInspect( person );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Metawidget Tutorial" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.getContentPane().add( metawidget );
        frame.setSize( 400, 250 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

**Domain Object:**

```
package com.myapp;

public class Person {
    private String  mName;
    private int     mAge;
    private boolean mRetired;

    public String getName() { return mName; }
    public void setName( String name ) { mName = name; }

    public int getAge() { return mAge; }
    public void setAge( int age ) { mAge = age; }

    public boolean isRetired() { return mRetired; }
    public void setRetired( boolean retired ) { mRetired = retired; }
}
```

If I remove the line 'frame.setSize( 400, 250 );' the Frame completely collapses and shows nothing. 
[Image of Collapsed Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQrBD.png)

Is there a way to show just enough of the JFrame to see all the components of the Metawidget(I will need to call pack() of the JFrame)? I am more concerned about the height. I can set a fixed width for it.

[Image of the JFrame with the right size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PstR1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `frame.pack();` and it worked. Sorry, my bad. The SwingMetaWidget is indeed returning the right Preferred Size. Apologies to anyone who might have spent time on this due to my error.